# Haproxy change part of url

Tags: haproxy

I have an app that was renamed and I want Haproxy to redirect to the correct path while preserving the request parameters

This is what I have:

```
acl old_name path_dir -i /old_name
   http-request set-path /new_name/%[query] if old_name
```

I want it to change from

```
www.site.com/old_name/Default.aspx?Id=123
```

to

```
www.site.com/new_name/Default.aspx?Id=123 but this is not working.
```

Comment: that this happen at IISM or MIT is not relevant and makes your question harder to understand. And what do you mean by "to have version control" ?

Comment: You're right, it's not really relevant to the question. By version control, I mean that you can actually see with a commit that you added a redirect for a url instead of being hidden in some config in IISM.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With HAProxy 1.5 : use a temporary header to build a new path from the existing one in the request and then directly perform a redirect

```
# Clean the request and remove any existing header named X-Rewrite
http-request del-header X-REWRITE

# Copy the full request URL into X-Rewrite unchanged
http-request add-header X-REWRITE %[url] if { path_beg /old_path }

# Change the X-REWRITE header to contain out new path
http-request replace-header X-REWRITE ^/old_path(/.*)?$ /new_path\1 if { hdr_cnt(X-REWRITE) gt 0 }

# Perform the 301 redirect
http-request redirect code 301 location http://%[hdr(host)]%[hdr(X-REWRITE)] if { hdr_cnt(X-REWRITE) gt 0 }
```

In HAProxy 1.6, use the regsub filter

```
http-request redirect code 301 location http://%[hdr(host)]%[url,regsub(^/old_path,/new_path,)] if { path_beg /old_path }
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/meineerde/11865802f8338b18f123) among [other useful configuration snippets](https://gist.github.com/meineerde)

More information is available in the [HAProxy documentation for the regsub keyword](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#7.3.1-regsub).

Comment: @flint When copying things you find on the internet verbatim, you should at least add some attribution to [the source](https://gist.github.com/meineerde/11865802f8338b18f123) (which would be me in this case).

Comment: You caught me @Holger. But I usually do. Late thanks.

Comment: Lovely solution, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You are confusing *url redirection* with *url rewriting* to the backend.

Should you even want to *rewrite*, then according to the haproxy 1.6 documentation :

> - "set-path" rewrites the request path with the result of the evaluation of
>       format string . **The query string, if any, is left intact.**

So the correct configuration *in that case* would be :

```
acl old_name path_dir -i /old_name
http-request set-path /new_name if old_name
```

To **redirect** the user :

```
redirect location /new_name if old_name
```

Comment: Yeah I was a bit confused with those two. The thing is that I want redirect the user to /new_name/Default.aspx?Id=123 and keep the "Default.aspx?Id=123" part. Doing a redirect like you mentioned just redirects to /new_name instead of /new_name/Default.aspx?Id=123.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone trying to make changes from uri to REST API, **do not use the http-request redirect location** because the header data is lost. Use **http-request set-uri**.

```
http-request set-uri %[url,regsub(^/old,/new,)] if { path_beg /old }
```